# Image to byte array fails "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Tags: c#, image, gdi

let's assume I let the user choose an image from the computer. I load the file to a picture box. here is the conversion method:

```
    public static Image LoadImageFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        Image result = null;
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            return result;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        try
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromStream(fs))
            {
                ImageManipulation.RotateImageByExifOrientationData(image);
                result =(Image) image.Clone();
                image.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
            
        }

        return result;
    }
```

then, when the user clicks on the Save button, I convert the image into a byte array and save it into the database. here is the conversion code:

```
    public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
    {
        if (image == null)
            return null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ImageFormat imageFormat = image.RawFormat;
            ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == imageFormat.Guid);
            var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            if (codec != null)
                image.Save(ms, codec, encoderParameters);
            else
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

but the problem:
I have a jpg file on the disk. I can load it into my picture box without any problem. the picture is perfectly visible in it. but when I save it, the code gives me  "A generic error occurred in GDI+." Error at 'image.Save(ms, codec,encoderParameters)' line.

more odd incident: I don't get this error all the time. it is happening with specific images. for example, I downloaded an image from the internet and crop it in "Paint" and saved it as jpg. error happened. open it in Paint again and save it as png. no error!!!! that is why I am really confused . and Yes I already have tried to don't dispose the image. not helping

I know it might be a stupid question but I am desperately stuck here :)

Thank you in Advanced

Comment: Possibly, you have cloned the file handle with `Clone`, closed the file, and GDI is chucking a spaz for one reason or another... Its only a guess. Clone has some serious quirks, the first thing i would do is try this another way

Comment: When it fails with the GDI+ error, are you getting a valid codec returned from the Linq you constructed?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out why my code is not working but I just substitute my loading method with the code below. it is releasing the file and at the same time works as it should.

```
        public static Image LoadImageFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        using (Bitmap bmb = new Bitmap(fileName))
        {
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            bmb.Save(m, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            return Image.FromStream(m);
        }
    }
```